# Modify User property in MVC Controller vs ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a custom `IPrincipal` called `UserPrincipal` which I use within my controllers. I use a base controller to set the `User` then implement that base controller within all my other MVC controllers. My `BaseController`:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected virtual new UserPrincipal User
    {
        get { return HttpContext.User as UserPrincipal; }
    }
}
```

That works perfectly well however now I am attempting to setup an API using using the `ApiController` class. I would like those `ApiControllers` to use the same `UserPrincipal` so I have essentially copied and pasted the same code into a `BaseApiController` class:

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    protected virtual new UserPrincipal User
    {
        get { return HttpContext.User as UserPrincipal; }
    }
}
```

This second version has a Compiler error at `HttpContext.User` stating the following:

> Cannot access non-static property 'User' in static context.

What is different about the `ApiController` from `Controller` and why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

`ApiController` already has a property called `User` which returns an `IPrincipal`

[MSDN: ApiController.User Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.user(v=vs.118).aspx)

If I correctly understand what you wish to do, then I believe that you should be able to leverage this property without adding any custom code or other properties.

Answer (score 1):

I came by this solution with the help of David Tansey's answer. Instead of `HttpContext.User` I use `base.User`.

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    protected virtual new UserPrincipal User
    {
        get { return base.User as UserPrincipal ?? new UserPrincipal("defaultuser"); }
    }
}
```

I added that `null` check and supplied a default user because the casting will result in `null` if the user isn't logged in and I don't want to `null` check constantly throughout my application.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the principal. See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api for more information.

```
private void SetPrincipal(IPrincipal principal)
{
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
    }
}
```

Also look into Token-based authentication.